# CustomerDAO alternative when Customer's fields are retrieved both from a third-party web-service and application's dedicated database

Tags: java, design-patterns, persistence, dao

I have a `Customer` class. Its private field is a `CustomerDAO` interface which database-access methods are called by `myCustomer.getAge()` for example. CustomerDAO retrieves data from the application's dedicated database.

The problem is that a few fields of `Customer` now have to be retrieved from a third-party web-service. Logically calling some web-service doesn't belong to `CustomerDAO` (which is intended for communicating with a single database, right?).

What is the industry recommended approach in such cases?

Shall I just add another field `CustomerWebServiceDAO` (as interface) to `Customer`? And my `Customer` would use internally two different instances (`CustomerDAO` and `CustomerWebServiceDAO`). So DAO gets split into 2 separate classes... *What if next I need access to another Web-service plus an additional database?* What better solution/pattern can be used?

Adding web-service methods to initial CustomerDAO interface would mix database access with web-service access, which I think is not good.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right
you need to have a database service which has all GRUD operation of **Customer** and assume it will be called **CustomerDBDao** and another service Called **CustomerAPIDao** which is responsible of all web service operations and all services is called in a general service called **CustomerDAO**
which is filling data from both services and generate One Unified POJO this concept is called adapter design patter

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/adapter_pattern.htm